# Stripe agregar metodos de pago en cuenta de prueba

Tags: php, stripe

Estoy implementando pagos con Stripe para una serie de productos para un sitio web. Todo bien por el momento, pero tengo un detalle, quiero agregar mas metodos de pagos en la creacion del id de session. No me funciona cambiarlo o agregar un keyword al array de payment methods.

Me pueden compartir si esto pasa porque estoy usando un modo de prueba? o como seria probar agregar nuevos metodos de pago usando API Keys de prueba y no las de produccion.

Por el desarrollo tengo un servidor de prueba con una cuenta de Stripe de prueba para probar la integracion de esta manera primero.

El codigo para crear la id de session en el lado del servidor va algo asi:

```php
public function create_session() {
    $payload = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $json = json_decode($payload,true);
    $obj = json_decode(json_encode($json));
    
    try{
      $customer_id = $obj->customer_id;
      $price_id = $obj->price_id;
      $cancel_url = $obj->cancel_url;
      $success_url = "http://example.com/success";
      
      $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(STRIPE_KEY);
      
      $session_id = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
        'success_url' => $success_url,
        'cancel_url' => $cancel_url,
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => [
          [
            'price' => $price_id,
            'quantity' => 1,
          ],
        ],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'locale' => 'en',
        'customer' => $customer_id,
      ]);
      
      $json = json_encode($session_id);
      
      http_response_code(200);
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo $json;
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      $mess = array(
        "error" => "Exception thrown",
      );
      http_response_code(400);
      echo json_encode($mess);
      exit();
    }
  }
```

Los parametros del cancel_url, y el customer_id y price_id los traslado desde el lado de cliente con JS y todo funciona bien, mi pregunta va dirigida especificamente a los metodos de pago

```php
...
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
...
```

Comment: Revisa estos enlaces: [Agregar métodos de pago](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-payment-methods), [métodos de pago disponibles en tu cuenta](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payments) y [Procesar otros métodos de pago](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/local-payment-methods).

Comment: Gracias, parece que la cuenta necesita estar activada para agregar metodos de pago, queria confirmar si con una cuenta de test se podia agregar, parece que no